# jQuery only performing one CSS transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, transform

I have a carousel that needs to be animated in 3D space in IE. So I am chaining the transforms on each child element to make this happen and it works...but only partially.

The jQuery call I make to rotate the individual divs will overwrite the current inlines styles one of which is the translateZ. So I put the translateZ into the function along with the transform rotateY but now jQuery decides to do one or the other and not both.

Here is my code...

```
    carouselAnimate = function () {
    var angle = $('.carousel').data('angle');
    var translate = $('.carousel').data('translate');
    var rotation = 0;
    var count = 0;
    $(".carouselImgs").each(function() {
        if(count === 0){
            rotation = 0;
        }else{
            rotation = rotation + angle;
        }
        var nxtStep = rotation + angle;
        $(this).css({
            transform: 'rotateY(' + nxtStep +'deg)' + 'translateZ(' + translate +'px)'

        });
        count++; 
    });
};

<div class="carousel" data-angle="<?php echo $imgArray[0]["angle"]; ?>" data-translate="<?php echo $imgArray[0]["translateZ"]; ?>">
 <?php foreach ($imgArray as $img) : ?>
                <div class="carouselImgs" style="transform: rotateY(<?php echo $img["rotateY"]; ?>) translateZ(<?php echo $img["translateZ"]; ?>); 
                     -webkit-transform: rotateY(<?php echo $img["rotateY"]; ?>) translateZ(<?php echo $img["translateZ"]; ?>);">
                    <img src="<?php echo $img["img"]; ?>"/>
                </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Now of course I still need to get this into an animation but I was gonna worry about that later, first I just need to get both rotateY and translateZ to fire, because again...as of now jQuery will only run one of them and then overwrite what was already there.

Comment: call one transform then call the other transform instead of trying to combine them.... maybe

Comment: that didn't work unfortunately